# Enumerate sks files in Bundle

Tags: swift

I want to list .sks in the bundle. They are the levels of my game. I just want to know how many levels are in the bundle by discarding the rest of the .sks
I tried this

```
let listSKS = Bundle.main.path(forResource:".//Stage1", ofType: "sks")
print(listSKS)
```

Return -> ("/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2B72AD87-E6FE-45FF-9DCC-AB0F27F2F353/Madness Jumping.app/./Stage1.sks")

```
let listLevels = GameScene(fileNamed: ".//Stage1")
print(listLevels)
```

Return -> Optional( name:'Stage1' frame:{{-896, -414}, {1792, 828}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5})

```
let listSKS2 = Bundle.main.path(forResource:".//Stage*", ofType: "sks")
print(listSKS2)
```

Return -> nil

```
let listLevels2 = GameScene(fileNamed: ".//Stage*")
print(listLevels2)
```

Return -> nil

Answer (score 0):

You should use `urls(forResourcesWithExtension:)` instead

```
let listSKS = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: ".sks", subdirectory: nil)
```

And to get just the filenames:

```
if let listSKS = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: ".sks", subdirectory: nil) {
    let files = listSKS.map(\.lastPathComponent).filter({$0.prefix(5) == "Stage"})
    print(files)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This list all SKS files in Bundle.

Comment: @NicanorBurcio Updated my answer to only include sks files which names starts with "Stage"

Answer (score 0):

You can filter sks files with "Stage" as below:

```
let filePrefix = "Stage"
if let fileURLs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "sks", subdirectory: nil) {
     let filteredArray = fileURLs.filter{ $0.lastPathComponent.range(of: "^\(filePrefix)", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil }
     print("Filtered Array",  filteredArray)
}
```

Comment: Could you accept it as an answer if it works. Thank you

Comment: The system won't let me mark as an answer because I'm a newbie here. Sorry.